# What is the legal status of Patent 6869679B1

Tags: legal, status

what is the legal status of this patent [US6869679B1](https://encrypted.google.com/patents/US6869679)

Answer (score 0):

An excellent way to check the status of US patents is the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site. In this case, the patent has been granted and all fees have been paid. Both the inventor and assignee is listed as Edward Negola. It is possible the assignee has changed. I would expect the patent to expire 20 years from its priority date in Oct 8, 2022. There is a divisional patent published as [US7335414B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7335417B2/en) with the assignee as Aquadye Fibers, Inc. It shares the priority date with US6869679B1.